# Relative velocity of two cars

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

Two cars A and B are at $100\,\text{m}$ and $200\,\text{m}$ distance from the origin $O$ at time $t = 0$.

They start simultaneously with velocities $10\,\text{m/s}$ and $5\,\text{m/s}$ respectively. A will overtake B at a distance of $x$ from $O$.

The answer given: $300\,\text{m}$.

What I have tried so far: I tried to calculate the relative velocity of car A and then to find out the time and the distance but I got stuck. And each time I try, I go with a different approach, so, really, I haven't a clue even  on how to proceed to solve this problem.

Comment: "And each time I try, I go with a different approach" - That's an interesting observation. Have you tried to calm down and observe yourself why your reasoning is so chaotic? Some other people learn the art of self-control so every time they try, they may repeatedly use the same correct approach that they previously identified to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are many ways to approach the problem, The simplest, the first that comes to my mind is : find the time it takes.

Think of the time it takes A to cover/catch up the difference in space using the difference of speed.

P.S I hope this hint is not against the rule, if it is, just tell me and I delete my answer.